Where does darktable store image tags?
Darktable has what seems to be useful image tagging functionality, but where does it store those tags?
Are they written to the file itself as metadata, or are tags only stored in external files?
I.e. would tags applied to an image in darktable on Windows show up here in Windows Explorer?

Tags are not so useful if they can only be used within darktable itself.

What was the result when you tried it out? Did the tags show up in Windows Explorer?

Did the darktable docs make this any clearer for you?

The Windows "Tags" property will read data from multiple different embedded tags, which are EXIF:XPKeywords, IPTC:Keywords, XMP-dc:Subject. The EXIF:XPKeywords is basically a Windows only tag that most software will not read. IPTC:Keywords is the older IPTC IIM standard, which isn't as flexible or limited as the more modern XMP standard.

@StarGeek, in my opinion, what you posted should be posted in the form of an answer.

My comment didn't answer the question. It only detailed what Windows does, not what Darktable does.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90088/60903 treads similar ground.

@osullic Answer to comment 1: they did not. Answer to comment 2: they did.

Darktable stores metadata in XMP sidecar files (see tagging). This is standard with more advanced image programs, as it allows quick and simple updating of metadata without having to rewrite the entire file, as well as quicker backups, as only the small sidecar would need backing up rather than the entire file.
There are programs, such as ExifTool (commnd line program), that can copy the data from the sidecar into the image. See ExifTool's Metadata Sidecar Files example #15 for a command that will do this in batch.

It may also store them in it's central catalog, but I haven't dug into it that much. I know it stores enough in that central catalog to recreate those XMP sidecars if they get corrupted or go missing, so it would stand to reason the tags might also be included there.

That's quite probable. I don't use DT, but if it has any metadata search ability, then there would need to be a database of some sort.

@twalberg You are correct. From the metadata and tagging page "This information is stored in darktable’s database and XMP sidecar files "

@StarGeek, are you 100% sure because AFAIK some fileformats store like JPEG, DNG store this meta information inside, and some products do not care about XMP when dealing with such formats?

@RomeoNinov Sorry, I can't be 100% sure, as I don't use the program. I'm simply pointing out what it says on their website. But this recent exiftool forum post seems to indicate it is true for DNG files. And this post indicates the same for JPEGs. Personally, I would hope there would be an option to embed the data in the file instead of a sidecar, but my quick search doesn't find anything.

@StarGeek, AFAIK this meta info is always embedded for JPEG and DNG and most of the software I use do not case in such case about the info in .xmp. About exiftool forum post: the format which is expected is filename.cr2, filename.xmp, not .cr2.xmp

Yes there is a database, yes darktable uses xmp sidecars. This is because even exiftool concedes that trying to alter the metadata of propriety raw files is risky. darktable also has the ability too export .jpg or whatever with embedded metadata. darktable man - metadata preferences. It even allows mapping one tag on to another ie taking a 'caption' and adding it to the 'user comment' and  IPTC 'description' tags.

@dmkonlinux, IMHO you do not get the point of OP. The question is where is stored meta information in general, not specifically in export. And I explicitly mention it is stored in general IN the files (for JPEN and DNG)

@dmkonlinux Do you have a source for "even exiftool concedes…", because that is not something I recall Phil (author of exiftool) has ever said. He works incredibly hard to make sure nothing ever goes wrong when writing metadata.

@RomeoNinov, my thought process was that as darktable is a raw processor a user checking the metadata of a jpg in other software has probably exported that jpg first but of course that is not necessarily the case.

@StarGeek you know what, I can't. I just scanned the site but the closest I got was "Writing meta information is more complicated than it may appear at first glance, which may be one reason why there are very few utilities around that do it." and "many manufacturers store meta information in undocumented formats which must be reverse engineered....it is best to always preserve the original copy of your image file. The "exiftool" script does this for you automatically by renaming the original file and always working on a copy."
Really thought I'd read it...

@dmkonlinux No worries. I've been working with exiftool and active on its forums for over a decade now, and I still miss things. Which is why I asked a source. I thought it was something else I missed.
